# Unparseable date with extra number in Java

Tags: java, simpledateformat

What's wrong in this code? I'm trying to parse a date format that has 0 between years and months.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy'0'MMdd");
        try {
            Date date = format.parse("201600101");
            System.out.println(date);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs Unparseable date: "201600101". If I change '0' to anything but number [e.g. 'X' and format.parse("2016X0101")] this will work.

Comment: My guess is it sees `20160` as a year. `yyyy` could be 2,3,4,5 digit years.

Comment: If you know the format that prescriptively, why not just strip the extra zero out?

Comment: that's an interesting one .. it seems to work, once you add whitespace, so, e.g., the pattern "yyyy '0'MMdd" is interpreted as expected.

Comment: With yyyyy also does not work ("yyyyy'0'MMdd"), so mayby that is not connected with year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Peter Lawrey said Java sees `'20160'` as a year. You can solve your problem by modifying `"201600101"`  to, for example, `2016-00101` and refactor your format patter as

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-'0'MMdd");
```

That will parse your date.

Answer (score 1):

Using a library where you can use fixed widths of four digits for the year would do the trick. Example for `java.time`-package in Java-8:

```
    String input = "201600101";

    DateTimeFormatter dtf =
        new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4, 4, SignStyle.NEVER)
            .appendLiteral('0')
            .appendPattern("MMdd")
            .toFormatter();
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(input, dtf);
    System.out.println(date); // 2016-01-01
```

This has the strong advantage not to be forced to change the input. It is always better to change the formatter. Admittingly, not possible with `SimpleDateFormat`.